# Spring Data JPA specification: entity-collection contains all elements

Tags: java, spring, jpa, hibernate-criteria

Happy new Year!

I have an entity that has a List of another Entity. Let's say Entity A has a List of Entity B. Entity B has a property called "name". I have a filter that is a list of String. These Strings are names that Entity B (could) have.

I want to find all items of "Entity A" where all the elements in the filter are represented through their name in A's List of Entity B.

I tried something like the code I've appended but the problem is that I first need to join the list of Entity B and than compare all the given names (my filter) with the names of the joined items..

I also tried .in(...) but this doesn't work, because I need AND for all the names in the filter, not OR.

```
public static Specification<PortalEntry> tags(List<String> tags) {
    return (Specification<PortalEntry>) (root, query, cb) -> {
        return tags.stream().map(tagName ->
                cb.isMember(tagName,
                        root.joinList(PortalEntry_.tags.getName()))
        ).reduce(cb::and).get();
    };
}

--> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
unknown collection expression type [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.
ListAttributeJoin]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
unknown collection expression type [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.
ListAttributeJoin]
```

Comment: You'll need a subquery, to check that the count of names in the tags of a portalEntry that are also in the list is equal to the size of the list (which should really be a Set, BTW).